# how to encrypt folder in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, cryptography

A folder on File System contains .xml files, .txt files and a file exposed by third party tool. Using c# (in VS 2008), I want to encrypt the whole folder in someway before transferring it through FTP.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: So you want to zip the folder with an password?

Comment: ya.. that too can work, if you think it is really enough secure. How i gonna do that?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you trust both sides of the file transfer, you can use SCP (file transfer over SSH) or FSTP instead, so all the communication will be encrypted.

If you don't want to, or can't, then you can encrypt the files, there is good [MSDN guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010) on how to encrypt/decrypt files.

Comment: Encrypting the file and sending it over an insecure protocol is not a complete solution. I agree with Am: use TLS (SSL), SCP, SFTP, etc. as well.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip) library. It provides API to ZIP and Encode files and folders.